# Android "No content provider found for permission revoke"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a simple app HelloWorld Android app in Eclipse (Mac OS X), when I install to the emulator/AVD the app shows up in "Settings->[Devices] Apps" but not in the launcher. I notice in logcat that I get these errors

```
W/ActivityManager(  160): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/HelloWorld.apk
W/ActivityManager(  160): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/HelloWorld.apk
I/PackageManager(  160): Running dexopt on: com.example.helloworld
D/dalvikvm(  870): DexOpt: load 124ms, verify+opt 459ms, 720236 bytes
I/ActivityManager(  160): Force stopping package com.example.helloworld uid=10044
```

I have set read/write/execute permissions on the .android directory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9532683/165674 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8646393/165674 http://stackoverflow.com/q/11073358/165674

Comment: Thanks, but I've read and tried the recommendations from that thread

Comment: @Sean ThreadS, you mentioned the `.android` and `/data/local` directory permissions, what about [deleting `dalvik-cache`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532653/android-4-0-3-emulator-install-fails-with-permission-revoke/9532683#9532683)?  [Trying with this app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073358/android-error-message-on-install-no-content-provider-found#comment14494371_11073358)? [Trying another device](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074769/85950)?  Do those all give the same error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case I forgot to define **main** activity. So, I add the following code inside AndroidManifest.xml **main** activity.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

That was the result for Activity definition:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="RssfeedActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="DetailActivity"></activity>        
</application>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that the problem is with the install directory permissions. `/data/local` needs to have write and execute rights to others in order for adb packages to install correctly.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8639873/1420197)

Try this, too: [Android - Download App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10918150/1420197)

Answer (score 1):

I just found solution to Linux, but I not found for Windows, maybe because in Windows the directories and permissions were confused.

It's work for me: Add the user "Everyone" in folder "C://YourUser//.Android//" with full control, then restart the emulador.

Comment: I just changed permissions and ownership for the `avd` subfolder and that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on all of my devices. My problem was from the run configuration, I didn't checked the "launch default Activity".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem building a new signed APK.

I checked the V2(Full APK signature). Installing the APK on a device did not work anymore.

My solution was to check the V1 (Jar signature) instead. This did work.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. What does 'check' mean in this context? Where are the signatures you're 'checking'? What does it mean for the solution to 'work'?

Comment: I guess he is talking about android studio -> generate signed apk -> sign with V1 option

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8646393/375929 - they say it's about /data/local permissions.

And here: [Change /data/local Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774114/change-data-local-permissions) is how to fix this.

Comment: I chmod'ed /data/local to 755, but still having this problem

Comment: have you rebooted the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was to remove the android:sharedUserId-Tag in the AndroidManifest.xml...

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.my.app"

    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"

    android:versionCode="9"

    android:versionName="1.2.5" android:sharedUserId="mc">`

Answer (score 0):

Working on Cordova and emulator,

For me the problem was that the apk size was large and AVD RAM was too small,

problem happen when install new version of the apk and it failed with the message "No content provider found for permission revoke"

any one of those fixed the problem for me:

- uninstall the old apk manually before install the new version
- decrease the apk size
- increase the device RAM

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Check your manifest application, if it contains  this line
`tools:replace="android:icon"`

`<application
        android:name=".activities.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon">`

make it like this by remove this line
 `tools:replace="android:icon"`

`<application
        android:name=".activities.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        >`