# Application not installing in android 4.0 ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When I try to install my application on Android 4.0.3 OS, I get following errors:

```
09-19 12:31:56.331: W/ActivityManager(107): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Sample.apk
09-19 12:31:56.340: W/ActivityManager(107): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Sample.apk
09-19 12:31:56.780: I/PackageManager(107): Running dexopt on: com.src.sample
09-19 12:31:57.060: I/ActivityManager(107): Force stopping package com.src.sample uid=10040
```

I have also tried this on a real device but applciation will not start.

My Application does not have a launcher icon.

AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsScreen"
    android:label="@string/setting_screen"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
  >
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

But this application successfully started on OS version 2.3.3 emulator and real device.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have faced similar issues, some pointers below

- [Android "No content provider found for permission revoke"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550798/android-no-content-provider-found-for-permission-revoke)
- [Android error message on install "no content provider found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073358/android-error-message-on-install-no-content-provider-found)
- [Cannot install APK on Android device through Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse)
- [Android - Download App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918150/android-download-app)

Kindly browse through them and figure out a solution.

Comment: I have go through all URL's and there is a solution from first URL •Android "No content provider found for permission revoke". Solution is add
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> in AndroidManifest.xml file
But after this solution my app launcher icon shows in the screen, but I don't want to 
show app icon in screen.

Comment: I would request you to google a bit more, i just spent 5 mins and found these 4 URLS's for you. Just do a little more digging.!