# Android app won't launch on emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

The debugger can't find anything wrong, and the app still won't launch: here is the the logcat and the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("UseValueOf") public  class MainActivity extends Activity  {
protected Double value1;
protected Double value2;
protected Double value3;
protected Double delta;
protected Double x1;
protected Double x2;
final EditText tf1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText tf2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final EditText tf3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
final TextView result1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
final TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
final Button caculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


@SuppressLint("UseValueOf") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tf1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
                setTextToString1();
        }
    });

    tf2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
                setTextToString2();
        }
    });

    tf3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            if(!hasFocus)
                setTextToString3();
        }

    }); 

caculate.setOnClickListener(null);
{
    if( !(value3.equals(null)&&value2.equals(null)&&value3.equals(null))  )
    {
        delta = new Double(caculateDelta(value1,value2,value3));
        x1 = caculateX(Math.sqrt(delta.doubleValue()));
        x2 =caculateX(-Math.sqrt(delta.doubleValue()));
        result1.setText(x1.toString());
        result2.setText(x2.toString());
    }
    else
    {
        result1.setText("Error");
        result2.setText("Error");
    }
}

}



public void setTextToString1()
{
    value1 = new Double(Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText().toString()));
}
@SuppressLint("UseValueOf") public void setTextToString2()
{
    value2 = new Double( Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText().toString()));   
    }
public void setTextToString3()
{
    value3 = new Double( Integer.parseInt(tf3.getText().toString()));
}

public double caculateDelta (double a, double b , double c)
{
    return b*b-(4*a*c);
}
public double caculateX (Double delta)
{
    return (-value2+delta.doubleValue()/(2*value1));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and here is the logcat, i have deleted the whole logcat and restart the app
then coppied that logcat:

```
03-22 19:57:47.946: D/AndroidRuntime(788): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-22 19:57:47.946: D/AndroidRuntime(788): CheckJNI is ON
03-22 19:57:48.036: D/dalvikvm(788): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-22 19:57:48.057: D/dalvikvm(788): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-22 19:57:48.135: D/dalvikvm(788): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-22 19:57:48.135: D/dalvikvm(788): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-22 19:57:49.786: D/AndroidRuntime(788): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-22 19:57:49.916: I/ActivityManager(299): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=799 uid=10009 gids={50009, 1015, 2001, 1028}
03-22 19:57:50.176: E/Trace(799): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 19:57:50.446: W/ActivityManager(299): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/SqureFunC.apk
03-22 19:57:50.836: W/ActivityManager(299): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/SqureFunC.apk
03-22 19:57:50.836: I/PackageManager(299): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl1616084389
03-22 19:57:51.416: I/PackageManager(299): Removing non-system package:com.eilonudi.squrefunc
03-22 19:57:51.416: I/ActivityManager(299): Force stopping package com.eilonudi.squrefunc appid=10046 user=-1
03-22 19:57:52.027: I/PackageManager(299): Package com.eilonudi.squrefunc codePath changed from /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-2.apk to /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
03-22 19:57:52.081: I/PackageManager(299): Running dexopt on: com.eilonudi.squrefunc
03-22 19:57:54.766: D/dalvikvm(813): DexOpt: load 383ms, verify+opt 1197ms, 800436 bytes
03-22 19:57:55.036: I/ActivityManager(299): Force stopping package com.eilonudi.squrefunc appid=10046 user=-1
03-22 19:57:55.066: W/PackageManager(299): Code path for pkg : com.eilonudi.squrefunc changing from /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-2.apk to /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-1.apk
03-22 19:57:55.066: W/PackageManager(299): Resource path for pkg : com.eilonudi.squrefunc changing from /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-2.apk to /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-1.apk
03-22 19:57:55.926: D/dalvikvm(299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 529K, 25% free 5371K/7116K, paused 95ms+21ms, total 295ms
03-22 19:57:55.996: D/PackageManager(299): New package installed in /data/app/com.eilonudi.squrefunc-1.apk
03-22 19:57:56.266: I/ActivityManager(299): Force stopping package com.eilonudi.squrefunc appid=10046 user=0
03-22 19:57:56.566: D/dalvikvm(419): GC_EXPLICIT freed 106K, 16% free 3821K/4504K, paused 9ms+14ms, total 134ms
03-22 19:57:56.756: I/InputReader(299): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
03-22 19:57:56.796: I/ActivityManager(299): Start proc com.android.keychain for broadcast com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver: pid=815 uid=1000 gids={41000, 1015, 1028, 3002, 3001, 3003}
03-22 19:57:57.126: E/Trace(815): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 19:57:57.226: W/ContextImpl(815): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2376 
03-22 19:57:57.316: W/AccountTypeManager(602): No authenticator found for type=com.android.exchange, ignoring it.
03-22 19:57:57.326: I/AccountTypeManager(602): Loaded meta-data for 0 account types, 0 accounts in 12ms(wall) 6ms(cpu)
03-22 19:57:57.356: D/dalvikvm(453): GC_EXPLICIT freed 263K, 13% free 2708K/3108K, paused 13ms+14ms, total 1060ms
03-22 19:57:57.786: I/InputReader(299): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
03-22 19:57:58.376: W/InputMethodManagerService(299): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
03-22 19:57:58.456: W/AccountTypeManager(602): No authenticator found for type=com.android.exchange, ignoring it.
03-22 19:57:58.466: I/AccountTypeManager(602): Loaded meta-data for 0 account types, 0 accounts in 14ms(wall) 7ms(cpu)
03-22 19:57:58.556: I/ActivityManager(299): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=829 uid=10014 gids={50014, 1015, 1028}
03-22 19:57:58.796: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 38K, 8% free 2369K/2552K, paused 8ms+9ms, total 256ms
03-22 19:57:58.986: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 8% free 2369K/2552K, paused 13ms+18ms, total 190ms
03-22 19:57:59.096: E/Trace(829): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 19:57:59.206: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 8% free 2369K/2552K, paused 23ms+19ms, total 217ms
03-22 19:58:00.916: D/dalvikvm(299): GC_EXPLICIT freed 629K, 25% free 5340K/7116K, paused 75ms+102ms, total 1519ms
03-22 19:58:01.216: D/AndroidRuntime(788): Shutting down VM
03-22 19:58:01.296: D/dalvikvm(788): GC_CONCURRENT freed 94K, 18% free 467K/564K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 52ms
03-22 19:58:01.296: D/jdwp(788): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-22 19:58:01.296: D/dalvikvm(788): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-22 19:58:01.878: I/ActivityManager(299): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast com.android.quicksearchbox/.CorporaUpdateReceiver: pid=848 uid=10001 gids={50001, 3003, 1028}
03-22 19:58:02.596: E/Trace(848): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 19:58:03.256: D/AndroidRuntime(852): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-22 19:58:03.256: D/AndroidRuntime(852): CheckJNI is ON
03-22 19:58:03.436: D/dalvikvm(852): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-22 19:58:03.487: D/dalvikvm(852): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-22 19:58:03.506: W/RecognitionManagerService(299): no available voice recognition services found for user 0
03-22 19:58:03.616: I/Choreographer(419): Skipped 1174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:03.627: D/dalvikvm(852): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-22 19:58:03.627: D/dalvikvm(852): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-22 19:58:03.996: I/Choreographer(419): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:05.726: D/AndroidRuntime(852): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-22 19:58:05.746: D/dalvikvm(852): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 157 unimplemented (abstract) methods
03-22 19:58:05.837: I/ActivityManager(299): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.eilonudi.squrefunc/.MainActivity} from pid 852
03-22 19:58:05.909: D/PermissionCache(36): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (14464 us)
03-22 19:58:05.926: W/WindowManager(299): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21005
03-22 19:58:06.017: D/AndroidRuntime(852): Shutting down VM
03-22 19:58:06.067: D/dalvikvm(873): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-22 19:58:06.117: I/ActivityManager(299): Start proc com.eilonudi.squrefunc for activity com.eilonudi.squrefunc/.MainActivity: pid=873 uid=10046 gids={50046, 1028}
03-22 19:58:06.117: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 17% free 499K/596K, paused 2ms+7ms, total 75ms
03-22 19:58:06.128: D/jdwp(852): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-22 19:58:06.128: D/dalvikvm(852): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-22 19:58:06.786: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-22 19:58:07.046: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:07.156: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:07.366: E/Trace(873): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 19:58:07.756: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:08.046: I/Choreographer(419): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:08.296: I/try(873): start view
03-22 19:58:08.336: D/AndroidRuntime(873): Shutting down VM
03-22 19:58:08.336: W/dalvikvm(873): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eilonudi.squrefunc/com.eilonudi.squrefunc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at com.eilonudi.squrefunc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-22 19:58:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  ... 11 more
03-22 19:58:08.416: W/ActivityManager(299):   Force finishing activity com.eilonudi.squrefunc/.MainActivity
03-22 19:58:08.486: W/WindowManager(299): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21010
03-22 19:58:09.016: W/ActivityManager(299): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40e98aa0 u0 com.eilonudi.squrefunc/.MainActivity}
03-22 19:58:09.066: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 156 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:09.136: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-22 19:58:09.526: I/Choreographer(419): Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:09.727: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:09.826: I/ARMAssembler(36): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00008001_00000000 [113 ipp] (134 ins) at [0x40eb3460:0x40eb3678] in 2950837 ns
03-22 19:58:09.896: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.006: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.216: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-22 19:58:10.396: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.416: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.526: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.586: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.696: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:10.776: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.016: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.086: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.206: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.326: D/dalvikvm(299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 19% free 5785K/7116K, paused 14ms+83ms, total 1881ms
03-22 19:58:11.326: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.776: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.806: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.856: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.896: D/dalvikvm(419): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 201K, 16% free 3815K/4504K, paused 656ms, total 700ms
03-22 19:58:11.958: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:11.996: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:12.059: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:12.086: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:12.156: I/Process(873): Sending signal. PID: 873 SIG: 9
03-22 19:58:12.196: I/ActivityManager(299): Process com.eilonudi.squrefunc (pid 873) has died.
03-22 19:58:12.226: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:12.366: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 167 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:12.576: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:12.756: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:13.076: I/Choreographer(299): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 19:58:13.236: W/InputMethodManagerService(299): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4107b340 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@40f8fbc8
03-22 19:58:18.206: D/ExchangeService(691): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-22 19:58:18.206: D/ExchangeService(691): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
```

Comment: 1) Yellow lines are warnings. You want the red lines, aka errors. 2) Click on the top item from the logcat you want, then hold shift and click on the last one you want. Then you can use ctrl+c and copy it here.

Comment: You are trying to call findViewById in the constructor, before the view is created or you've called setContentView.  That's not going to work.

Comment: Nullpointer there: `MainActivity.java:69`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write your these lines in onCreate method after setContentView.

```
final EditText tf1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText tf2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final EditText tf3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
final TextView result1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
final TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
final Button caculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and Check your AndroidManifest.xml have your entry all correctly.

See these links

[Android "No content provider found for permission revoke"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550798/android-no-content-provider-found-for-permission-revoke)

[Application not installing in android 4.0 ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811933/application-not-installing-in-android-4-0-ics)

Comment: still the app wont lunch , i fixed all the things , for some reason now the logcat doesnt write anything in it

Comment: @EilonUdi Still have same then check the above links

Comment: i have checked the links but still was unable to understand what is wrong

Comment: @EilonUdi Check you have exeception at MainActivity.java:69